# Comparing Observing Techniques to Quantify the Effects of Starlink Satellites on Astronomical Observations

Tags: amateur-observing, photography, artificial-satellite

To take pictures of satellites I think I could use these methods listed below (are there more?)

**Method 1**

The satellites are tracked and their positions predicted. By utilising software tools and code libraries (such as Skyfield) available online, the satellites’ ephemerides are computed from their two line element (TLE) set. These software programs compute all the observable satellite passes for the forthcoming night. Next, the satellites’ images are captured. This will be done by pointing the telescope towards a satellite’s predicted location and tracking siderally.

**Method 2**

A possibility could be that of using an OpenAstroTracker (OAT) mount. Depending on the latitude of the observations, different versions of an OAT would be needed to be printed. The OAT would be controlled using a laptop interface via planetarium software. This would allow to download satellite TLE and tracking of which.

Both methods yield images of satellites:

Method 1 --> fixed stars with satellite streak

Method 2 --> streaked stars with fixed satellites

Now, to the question... Would it be feasible to compare these two methods? Perhaps capture the same satellite with these two methods. This would require two cameras however that could introduce some error as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How will Starlink affect observational astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34613/31410)

Comment: @fasterthanlight I don't see anything there that answers the OP's question about carrying out astrophotography for **Quantifying the Effects of Starlink Satellites on Astronomical Observations**. I don't see how this could be a duplicate. Instead I think it really deserves to be answered, and voting to close prevents anybody from doing that.

Comment: potentially helpful and just posted [Analytical simulations of the effect of satellite constellations on optical and near-infrared observations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.12335)

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand what you are asking. If you have multiple cameras, you surely could pursue both methods. But what do you mean when you ask if you can _compare_ them? Under what aspects would you like to compare them? Quality of the image? Difficulty of setup?

Comment: That's what I'm asking... How can I compare them... are they comparable at all?

Comment: I guess that the comparison criteria depend on what you want to achieve. I'm sorry, I don't get it. By the way, ti saluta Arturo ;)